# How to use graphics.h header file in C in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation

When I want to run program using graphics.h error "grprintf is undeclared in main" showing.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccN7XL3y.o: in function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `grprintf'
This error is seen when I try to run C program using gcc compiler in terminal.

Comment: What command do you issue to compile your program?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a [prior post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860710/10005669), <graphics.h> is an old library and deprecated in favor of other more-modern libraries such as [STL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), and [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/).

These libraries also have the benefit of allowing your code to be easily ported to other platforms.

If you are looking for a fully-fledged game engine, I would recommend looking into the [Godot Engine](https://godotengine.org/).